# Why does IP address need to be listed as a DNS name in SAN/UCC certs?

Tags: tls, certificates

I have heard that when creating a CSR that if you want to validate an IP address that you should list the IP as a "DNS" name and not "IP Address". I have actually had to re-create CSR's like this to fix clients that won't connect and browser SSL warnings. At first I thought it was something limited to self signed SSL certificates but now I've seen this behavior on CA certs. Why do CSR utilities give you the option to list an IP as an IP if this does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because verification is up to clients. And some of these didn't do a good job. So to support these you had to fiddle with the certificates.

[MichaelHolm.Info: IP addresses in SubjectAltName in SSL website certificates #fail for some browsers](http://www.michaelm.info/blog/?p=1281)

Answer (score 1):

> Why do CSR utilities give you the option to list an IP as an IP if this does not work?

I don't know which CSR utilities you refer too, but some of them target people who know what they do. Certificates are not restricted to browsers and the rules how they get used differ in other contexts. Especially the often used `openssl` is a tool which is able to create CSRs which are valid, but maybe not valid in the context of browsers. Thus it is definitely a tool for professionals who know the relevant standards and not for newbies.